# Why does inversion symmetry disallow valence band maximum (VBM) to conduction band minimum (CBM) electronic transitions?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, physical-chemistry, parity, quantum-chemistry

I have somewhere read that due to inversion symmetry in the crystal structure the electronic transition occurs from some bands below VBM and therefore optical band gap comes into the picture with a value greater than the transport/electronic/fundamental gap. Generally, for organic semiconductors, where exciton binding energy is high, the terminology of an optical band gap is prominent. However, I guess, not all organic semiconductors exhibit inversion symmetry. Then, what is the cause of the optical band gap in organic semiconductors?

Comment: The title and the body here ask different questions.