# Why does a lattice have to have an inversion center?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, group-theory, crystals

Indeed all lattices have inversion symmetry, but my teacher said a lattice has to have an inversion center: why? If a lattice doesn't have inversion symmetry, what would happen?

Comment: Please excuse me for posting another related question here. I didn't get any answer to my question- [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/690344/why-does-inversion-symmtery-disallow-valence-band-maximum-vbm-to-conduction-ba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/690344/why-does-inversion-symmtery-disallow-valence-band-maximum-vbm-to-conduction-ba), but found a related discussion here. In crystals with inversion symmetry, the electronic transition occurs not exactly from VBM but from some bands below it. Please shed some light in this regards.

Comment: Somewhat related: ["Lack of inversion symmetry" in crystal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In three dimensions a mathematical lattice (which crystallographers call a Bravais lattice) is the set of points $\{m\vec a + n\vec b + p\vec c\}$ where $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ are vectors which span space and $m,n,p$ are integers. If we invert a point of the lattice in the point $\vec q$ we get the point $2\vec q - m\vec a - n\vec b - p\vec c$. So if $2\vec q$ is a point of the lattice then inversion in $\vec q$ maps the lattice to itself, so $\vec q$ is an inversion centre for the lattice. In particular, $\vec q = \tfrac 1 2(\vec a + \vec b + \vec c)$ is an inversion centre for the lattice that is not on the lattice itself.

Comment: You mean *Bravais lattice* - many crystals do not have inversion symmetry.

Answer (score 7):

It is necessary to distinguish here between a lattice of points ([Bravais lattice)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice) and an actual crystal lattice, which may contain more than one atom in a cell (i.e., where some atoms are not accessible via the elementary translations). The former can be shown to have an inversion center, as discussed in the answer by @Gandalf. The actual crystal however may not have inversion symmetry.

Furthermore, the same crystal lattice may or may not have inversion symmetry, depending on the types of atoms it is filled with: e.g., Diamond and zinc oxide have the same crystal lattice, but the former one has inversion symmetry, while the latter doesn't: in diamond the two sublattices of the diamond lattice are filled with identical itoms, while in zinc oxide one is filled with zinc atoms and the other with the oxygen.

Comment: It is indeed an important point. Crystal=Lattice+Basis.

Answer (score 2):

Since translation symmetry would cause inversion symmetry, system without inversion symmetry could not have translation symmetry which is indispensable for a lattice.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. It's easy to define a set of points in space that has translation symmetry along any number of primitive vectors but no inversion symmetry. Of course such point sets are not [Bravais lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice), but there's nothing in this answer that explains why that's the case. (The other, earlier answer by gandalf61 at least gives the definition of a lattice, which can be used to show this.)

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of knowledge, could you please give some examples of point sets with translation symmetry along any number of primitive vectors but without any inversion centres.

Comment: Let $L$ be any lattice, let $U$ be a unit cell of $L$, and let $S \subset U$ be an arbitrary set with no inversion symmetry within the unit cell. (For example you could draw a smiley face inside the unit cell and call the points in your drawing $S$.) Now $X = L + S = \{\vec a \in L, \vec b \in S: \vec a + \vec b\}$ is a set with the same translation symmetries as $L$, but no inversion symmetry. (For visualization, if your $S$ was a smiley face drawn inside a unit cell of $L$, $X$ will have the same smiley face in _every_ unit cell of $L$.)

Comment: Thanks. I should utilize the explicit definition of lattice.

Comment: @Seornna see e.g. the (implied) sets of points in my answer to ["Lack of inversion symmetry" in crystal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal)